# How can I find entries in a group of scripts that contain text from a list?

Tags: bash, script

I have a list of search terms in termlist.txt, and a directory /dir/scripts which has a lot of scripts inside.

How would I easily determine if any file in /dir/scripts contains any term in the list from terms.txt?

This is on a unix server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Fxrlf termlist.txt /dir/scripts
```

where grep options are

- `-f file` use patterns from file
- `-F` patterns are fixed strings, not regular expressions
- `-x` the pattern must match the whole line (you may not want this)
- `-l` output only the filenames containing the match
- `-r` recursive

Comment: this seems to be exactly what I needed. Thanks